# I can't remove splash screen image in iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, splash-screen

I am testing my app on SDK iOS Simulator to make sure it runs properly. First of all, I decided to remove a splash screen image because I don't think I want one. When I ran my app again, it's showing the splash image again, thought I was a bit confused there, so I deleted the image from references and removed the image from the folder, to the trash. WHen I ran my ap again, it's still showing the same splash screen image again! I have no clue what's going on with my project now that the stupid splash screen image that I removed kept showing over and over again. Then I tried to run other project to see they are ok, but for some problem again, that same splash screen image that I completely removed is still showing up! Hopefully someone can Please help me resolve this situation quickly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clean the project (in xcode :-) ), remove any installed version of your app on the simulator (if you want, reset the simulator, it will be more efficient), go into the finder and with a rightclick on your xcode project, open the package and check if there are no included source file into it (.m, .h, resources, ...), including your image. If there are, move them out and update the needed one into your project. Then clean your project again in xcode, build, run.

Does this work ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Thought I was a goner with this stupid splash screen popping up!

Answer (score 7):

in xcode you need to do a build clean, then delete the app from the simulator, then build and run.

Answer (score 0):

See [Xcode- Deleted images appear in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821316/xcode-deleted-images-appear-in-simulator). You can also try removing the app from your simulator and running it again.