# Launch image can't be deleted from Xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, splash-screen

I added a launch image to my iPhone app in Xcode, but after while, I realized that it wasn't the right image, so I deleted it , but the problem, the image is still showing up on the app.

I have tried building and cleaning from scratch but still no luck .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you replaced the image with another one yet?

Comment: @TheEighthEro: I think I have given solution about `Copy Bundle Resources` which is definitely worth a try. Contact me if you need more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@TheEighthEro:

**SOLUTION**:

Considering that you have properly **deleted** the `Default.png`

In this `Target Settings` , go to `Copy Bundle Resources`. Remove the `Default.png` from there too.

Clean and Rebuild and Run the app. I am sure it won't show up then.

I think that should work for you.

**Also try refering to following links:**

[can't remove splash screen image in iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382360/cant-remove-splash-screen-image-in-ios-simulator)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/81470-cant-remove-splashscreen.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: @TheEighthEro: I think you might not have tried removing image from `Copy Bundle Resources` from `Target Settings`

Answer (score 2):

Did you remove the reference to the image in your app's info PLIST and/or the project build properties?  Did you delete the image from the filesystem or just delete the reference in XCode?  I would check both those things and then do a clean build.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was founded another reason to have it. If u disable to use asset catalog for launch images, but keep images inside image set, Xcode anyway using images from image set (definitely bug in Xcode). After removing, clean and removing app from a device/simulator, problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not possible. Every iOS app have a launch image, which you can change. The shorter your app takes to load, the shorter you’ll see that image. There is absolutely no way around this, since it’s something Apple specifically did to ensure that the user is never left with a black screen (that’s somewhere in the documentation I think).

If you want an animation, change your first scene to a scene with that animation, which redirects to your home scene after the animation is done. You can make your user think the launch image is part of the animation by having your first animation frame be the same as that image. That’s how most games do (Infinity Blade for example).

Link: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/custom-launch-image-solved/6055/5