# How many splash screens can be used in one application in ios?

Tags: ios, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

How many splash screens can be there in one iphone application.

If the answer is only one then what is the reason behind, like if there are other Views and they are talking long to load when app is in running state. Is it static or what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You manually create splash screens, so go ahead and make as many as you'd like.

Comment: so we can make anywhere inside the application...?

Comment: nothing I have got my point thanks....actually this [link]  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637974/want-to-change-splash-screen-every-time-the-app-launches-in-iphone) made me a little confused. So I was mixing two things...

Comment: They're referring to the launch image. That's just the image that appears until your app calls `didFinishLaunching...` You can create splash screens after that, freely.